# Math-font from the Ubuntu font family?

Tags: latex, ubuntu-font-family

Does anyone know if there will be (or already are) any possibilities to use the Ubuntu font family for mathematical typesetting in LaTeX?

It says “Dalton Maag, a London-based studio, has laid the foundations for the Ubuntu font project with a beautiful design that aims to produce every character to support every language and interest in the world.” on the [project web site](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/ubuntu-font) of Ubuntu. So I would expect something like this because maths is an interest.

Comment: You follow the steps in [this answer at tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27783/201). This should help you to get it working on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However, this does not work for typesetting math, as far as I know.